# Angularjs: how to position a popup menu (directive - service communication)

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I want to connect a popup menu with multiple input elements and show the menu when a new input element is focused. The menu closes on an "outside-of-menu click".

simplified example [plknr link](http://plnkr.co/edit/oqBIJu?p=preview) / code below.

I'm wondering about what is the most direct way to update the position of the popup menu for this situation. In other words: How to get the info about the newly focused input element back into the directive to make the changes there (position and value of the input element).

In my code I'm storing info about the position on a service (and also the reference to the currently focused input element), but this is not working (the directive does not update without scope.$apply) .

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $document, eventService) {

  $("input").on("focus", function(event) {
    $scope.$apply(function() {
      eventService.register(event.target, $scope);

      eventService.positon = $(event.target).position();
      $scope.position = eventService.position;
      console.log("in", $scope.position);

      eventService.addMenu();

    });

    console.log('from event', $(event.target).position());
  });

  $("input").on("blur", function() {
    console.log('blured');
    // eventService.closeList()
  });
});


app.directive("myMenu", function($document, eventService, $compile) {

  return {
    restrict: "A",
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {

    var menu = angular.element('<div id="menu" class="menu">menu {{menuText}}<div>');
    $compile(menu)(scope);

    eventService.input = $("input").first(); //set the first input
    scope.menuText = eventService.input.val();

    scope.$watch(function() {
      return eventService.input.val();
    }, function(newValue, ov) {
      scope.menuText = newValue;
    });


    // $document.off("dialogmutex", closeMenu);
    $document.on("dialogmutex", closeMenu);

    // close menu on outside click:
    $document.on("click", function(event) {
    // if the menu or input is clicked dont close it.
      if (!((event.target === elem[0]) || event.target === eventService.input[0] || (elem.find(event.target).length > 0))) {
          $document.trigger("dialogmutex");
      }
    });


    function addMenu() {
      // positioning the menu does not work 
      var pos = eventService.position;



      if (pos) {
        elem.css({
          top: pos.yPos,
          left: pos.xPos,
          position: 'absolute'
        });
      }

      console.log("directive position:", pos); 
      elem.append(menu);

      scope.menuText += " x "
    }

    function closeMenu() {
      elem.find("#menu").remove();
    }


    addMenu(); // open menu on app start
    eventService.addMenu = addMenu;        // open the menu later from the controller via service
      } 

  }; 
});


// service used to register a new input element with the directive.
app.service('eventService', function() {
  service = {
    register: function(el) {

      service.input = $(el);

      console.log('reg');

      service.position = service.input.position();
      console.log("on service", service.position)


    }

  };
  return service;

});
```

### Update:

I got it working using `ngStyle` directive on the container element and a positionCSS Object on the directive scope ,this way I only need to call `$scope.$apply` once (inside the event handler)

Answer (score 1):

Using `id` for each input and the using `.closest` in jQuery should do the trick. You can refer to [this](http://subliminalsources.com/9/building-angularjs-bootstrap-components-popover-directive-part-1/) link for detailed version.

Comment: thanks for the link, I will have a closer look at it.